# Automatically complete org-mode tasks in agenda based on headings in specific org file

Tags: org-mode

So I'm trying to set up a specific workflow with emacs. Basically, I'll have NFC tags around the house on the various things I need to deal with for chores and etc. As I do these tasks, I'll tap the tag with my phone and will have a heading added to an org file indicating that I've done this. (I can already do this much)

The next thing I want to do with it is add a hook to my agenda that will go through this file and match any new headings to whichever tasks I have in my agenda, completing these tasks for me.

I'm new to elisp though, so I'm hoping that I could get some direction on the creating the pieces I think I'll need to do this.

So I think I'll need:

1. A method to scan through my 'completed' file

- It'll mark any new heading it finds as being already found
- It'll ignore already found ones

2. A method to go through tasks in my agenda
3. A method to set these tasks as being completed

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: This is a wide-open question which could be answered in many different ways, each of which would require a blog post, rather than the couple of paragraphs that answers here usually consist of. My suggestion would be to ask it either on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/) or on the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html) or else start implementing and every time you get stuck somewhere ask a question to help you get unstuck. "Design the universe and give three examples" is not the kind of question that is suitable for this site.